# Why does compiler warn of unused result on function marked @discardableResult?

Tags: swift

The Swift 3 compiler is warning me of an unused result, even though I have marked the function with `@discardableResult`.

It is only occurring when calling the function on an optional variable, using the `?` syntax.

To simplify the problem, I created this sample code. (I had to put it in a project because the warning didn't show in a playground.)

```
class Foo {
    @discardableResult func bar() -> String? {
        return "bar"
    }
}

class Tester {
    func doSomething() {
        var foo: Foo?

        foo = Foo()

        foo?.bar() //Warning: Expression of type 'String?' is unused
        foo!.bar() //No warning
    }
}
```

Comment: Known bug https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1929 but claimed to be resolved. If not, you should tell them.

Comment: Though perhaps this one (mine) is the one to comment on: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1681

Comment: And we got our answer! The fix will be in Xcode 8.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1681), though the Swift gang seems to think it has been resolved. Maybe the fix hasn't made it into Xcode yet, or maybe they're just wrong.

**UPDATE** We got the official word: The fix will appear starting in Xcode 8.3.